# Rails s command returns syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails `s` command is not working, below is what I get. Line 7, where the syntax error is: require 'psych/parser'. Not sure how to correct this error.

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 7 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:21:in `raw'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:123:in `initialize'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in `new'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in `instance'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:90:in `inherited'
    from /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/config/application.rb:17:in `<module:Bloccit>'
    from /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Generally this error is due some malformed yml file. Can you check your database.yml for spaces or tabs that shouldn't be there?

Comment: Check all your YAML config, it's often a mixed tabs/spaces or funky newlines etc.

Comment: Can you actually paste that file here, if you haven't found it? NOTE -- if it contains personal info, SWITCH IT OUT.

Comment: @Sasha application.yml file:

SENDGRID_PASSWORD: xyz
SENDGRID_USERNAME: xyz
DEVISE_SECRET_KEY: xyz
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: xyz
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: xyz
development:
 AWS_BUCKET: x-y-bloccit-development
production:
 AWS_BUCKET: x-y-bloccit-production

Comment: Amanjot -- YAML is a white-space dependent language. The indentation is very important. Can you edit your ANSWER to show the file with the whitespaces as in your app?

Comment: Indentation error, all fixed! :)